# update-rc.d wildfly defaults not working ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, bash, scripts, upstart, services

I am facing this issue in Ubuntu 16.04
Error during setup wildfly as service with the help of link
https://gesker.wordpress.com/2016/02/09/wildfly-10-on-ubuntu-15-10/
Showing below exception

```
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script haproxy missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script haproxy
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script haproxy
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script elasticsearch missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script elasticsearch
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script elasticsearch
```